# Group by PostgreSQL error

Tags: postgresql, sql

Quiero agrupar los diferentes códigos con el mismo precio para cada uno en monedas diferentes.

```
select clp.*, clp.c_precio as precio_clp,usd.c_precio as precio_usd, uf.c_precio as precio_uf FROM
          (SELECT *  FROM  itsa.c_listado_piso AS p where p.c_moneda ='CLP VA' group by p.c_codigo ) as clp,
          (SELECT *  FROM  itsa.c_listado_piso AS p where p.c_moneda ='USD FOB' group by p.c_codigo) as usd,
          (SELECT *  FROM  itsa.c_listado_piso AS p where p.c_moneda ='UF' group by p.c_codigo) as uf
```

Y quiero hacer un `GROUP BY` y me sale este error

```
 SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "p.c_listado_piso_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or 
 be used in an aggregate function
 Position: 118
```

Data desde database
[image]

Me gustaría algo así como obtener algo como esto.

```
   c_codigo     |c_esp|c_largo|precio_clp |precio_usd|precio_uf|
    ------------|-----|-------|-----------|----------|---------
   PISOCK2080-N |20   |MIX    | 27833     | 25.61    | 0.9883  |
   PISOCK20105-N|20   |MIX    | 27833     | 25.61    | 0.9883  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma que creo puede resolver tu preguna, al menos tal como parecieras que son los datos, es una consulta de agregación que condcionas a cada moneda:

```
SELECT c_codigo,
       c_esp,
       c_largo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c_moneda ='CLP VA' THEN c_precio ELSE NULL END)  as precio_clp,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c_moneda ='USD FOB' THEN c_precio ELSE NULL END) as usd,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c_moneda ='UF' THEN c_precio ELSE NULL END)      as precio_uf
       FROM  itsa.c_listado_piso 
       GROUP BY c_codigo,
                c_esp,
                c_largo
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta adjunto una imagen https://ibb.co/4R84prT, al hacer un GROUP BY obtengo ese listado de precios

Comment: @MoteCL, pero lo que me muestras no tiene un `group by`.

Comment: Te mostré con un `WHERE` para que vieras los 3 precios distintos.
Pero la idea miá es hacer un `SELECT * ` con un GROUP BY c_codigo y asi obtener los 3 precios distintos

Comment: @MoteCL, ¿has probado el código de mi respuesta?

Comment: Me agrupa bien, pero los precio estan malos https://ibb.co/9gZgQdK

Comment: ¿Que significa que están malos? lo que veo aquí https://ibb.co/4R84prT es que los precios para este código son 27833, 25.61 y 0.983. Cuando voy a ver la agrupación:  https://ibb.co/9gZgQdK, para ese mismo código, están los mismo precios que te mencioné en tres columnas distintas. Tal vez no terminé de entender tu pregunta.

Comment: Quiero poder agrupar los codigos con sus distintos precios. Me equivoque de foto aqui una mas clara con los precios y tipo de moneda https://ibb.co/F0GZnDQ

Comment: Lo siento, pero no logro entender. Veo tu pregunta, veo la salida que esperas, veo la salida en esta imagen https://ibb.co/9gZgQdK y no encuentro diferencia, salvo por el hecho que mi consulta dice `usd` y en tu caso dice `precio_usd` y que hay más filas con otros códigos.

Comment: Perdon no me percate pero esta bine la query